# using power bank to power a nema 17 stepper

Tags: power-supply, motor, stepper-motor

I was wondering if it is possible to power [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Geeetech-stepper-motor-Nema17-shaft-for-5mm-GT2-pulley-RepRap-Prusa-Mendel-/261824101971?hash=item3cf5eebe53:g:eEIAAOSwBLlVEoS~) 
3.75V/1.7A nema 17 stepper with a power bank which have a 5v/1A output like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/30000mAh-Dual-USB-Portable-Solar-Battery-Charger-Power-Bank-For-Cell-Phone-/231729740586?var=&hash=item35f42b3b2a:m:m3Z3PqFSJj7FYcCkXvF_pSg) one for example . 
Ps: I am new to the electronic world .

Comment: Welcome to SE. You need to show a bit of research with your question (and capitalise your words properly if you want to be taken seriously). Extract the relevant parts of the datasheets and post them in your question so we don't all have to look them up. Ask for clarification on the bits you don't understand.

Comment: I was asking if there is possibility to use a regular Li-polymer power bank as a power supply for a Nema 17 (you can find it's features in the link ) , and is there any risk of burning the power bank .

Comment: You could probably come up with a circuit to run it at reduced current.  However, it's going to be disappointing.  As many questions covered here before (which you will see in the sidebar) explain, to get decent performance from a stepper at more than low speed, you need a supply voltage several times the rated winding voltage and a chopping current regulator.  A converted PC or laptop 12v supply would be about the minimum for your motor, and something in the 18-24v range would be better, if you have a chopping driver board that can accept that.

Answer (score 1):

That motor requires 1.5A per phase for full torque, and to step properly both phases must be powered, so you need a power supply that can deliver at least 3A.

However you *could* use a 1A power supply if you are willing to accept lower torque. To do this you must limit the current to 0.5A per phase or less. Current can be limited by adding resistors in series with the windings. The resistance required can be calculated using Ohms Law, Resistance = Volts / Amps. 5V/0.5A = 10Ω. Since the phase resistance is 2.5Ω, your resistors need to be 7.5Ω or higher. At 0.5A the torque will only be about 1/3, and it won't be able to step very fast.

To get maximum performance you will need a bigger power supply. Even though the motor is rated for 3.75V, using a higher voltage will make it step faster because it overcomes inductance and forces current into the windings quicker.

The driver must limit current to 1.5A per phase using resistors or PWM (Pulse Width Modulation). PWM is more efficient because it doesn't waste power. Power = Volts x Amps. At 12V the resistors would have to dissipate (12V-3.75V)*0.5A = 4.125 Watts each, so they would get pretty hot!